# Convert ASP.NET MVC4 SPA AntiForgeryToken to PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, bundling-and-minification, antiforgerytoken

I do have SPA application that use some functionality of ASP.NET MVC4 like AntiForgeryToken.

I don't know how to implement AntiForgeryToken functionality in HTML without use of CSHTML which is not supported in Phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of the AntiForgery token in ASP.NET MVC relies on the HTML helper which generates a hidden input field and sets a cookie. If you cannot use this helper you will have to roll this functionality by yourself.

Comment: Hi Darin. Thanks for your fast answer.  Problem is if I want to deploy application to PhoneGap I cannot use ASP.NET MVC. Do you know how to implement this functionality without rely on server to generate HTML ?

Comment: You cannot implement this functionality without a server side script. This doesn't make any sense. The whole point of the antiforgery token is to have a server which generates this token.

Comment: OK. I have idea that I create simple HTML page that will make AJAX request to some method on ASP.NET WebAPI that will generate token and return it to client. Than I can use this token in my next request to WebAPI ? Something like that. What do you think ?

Comment: You cannot have a simple HTML page. You need to include some dynamic value into this HTML text that is generated by the server.

Comment: Yes but then it appears that I cannot use AntiForgeryToken functionality with PhoneGap...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am telling you :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a secure way to implement an anti-forgery token without a server generated page:

1. Create a controller or web api method that sets an HTTP only cookie with your anti-forgery token value and returns the anti-forgery token value (as JSON).  There is a public method [AntiForgery.GetTokens()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery.gettokens%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) that is called by [Html.AntiForgeryToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Use this method to read the token value in C# code.
2. Call the controller or web api method (in step 1) from javascript in your phonegap app and take the returned anti-forgery token and add it to the form using javascript (use a hidden input field named _RequstVerificationToken).
3. Submit the form to a method attributed with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and it should validate appropriately.

Microsoft has provided a very similar example implementation [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) (see section titled 'Anti-CSRF and AJAX').

On the surface this may seem insecure because you have a controller method that sets and returns the anti-forgery token, but web browsers enforce the [same origin security policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks should not be possible.

Since phonegap uses local files it is not subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440725/how-ajax-call-is-working-in-mobile-app-phonegap-but-not-in-pc-browser)) so it will be able to make AJAX requests to any domain specified in your config.xml ([see <access origin="..." /> here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml))