# Is there a cross site issue when accessing a webservice from a phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors

I would like to access an external web service from a phonegap app using ajax without having to resort to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control) or JSONP to circumvent the cross origin issue. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440725/how-ajax-call-is-working-in-mobile-app-phonegap-but-not-in-pc-browser) question, it would appear that cross site http calls are not an issue with phonegap based apps. However, there are some conflicting comments in the answer. Is anyone able to provide a definitive answer to this question within the context of phonegap for ios/andriod platforms?

Answer (score 0):

With phonegap, the only thing you have to do is allow access to the server by configuring `access origin` in config.xml.

No need of CORS or JSONP like you would have to do for example with rhodes.